# Can i use fileEntry object (I have list of fileEntry objects) to Upload file using chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, chromium

I have one retainEntry for directory so i can loop over it and get list of FileEntry Objects , but i want to upload those files , so can i use FileEntry Object to append in formdata object and upload it ?

**Menifest.json**

```
"permissions": [
    "alarms","notifications", {"fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries", "directory"]},
    "storage","http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
  ],
```

**My Action.js**

```
    var chooseDirButton = document.querySelector('#choose_dir');
    var outputdir = document.querySelector('#outputdir');
    chooseDirButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openDirectory'}, function(theEntry) {
    chrome.storage.local.set({'chosenFile': chrome.fileSystem.retainEntry(theEntry)});
     loadDirEntry(theEntry)
    });
});



   function loadDirEntry(_chosenEntry) {
      chosenEntry = _chosenEntry;
      if (chosenEntry.isDirectory) {
        var dirReader = chosenEntry.createReader();
        var entries = [];
        // Call the reader.readEntries() until no more results are returned.
        var readEntries = function() {
           dirReader.readEntries (function(results) {
            if (!results.length) {
              console.log(entries.join("\n"));
              displayEntryData(chosenEntry);
            }
            else {
              results.forEach(function(item) {
                // here irem is FileEntry Object , how can i upload file using this FileEntry Object?
                chrome.fileSystem.getDisplayPath(item, function(path) {
                 entries = entries.concat(path);
               });
                entries = entries.concat(item.fullPath);
              });
              readEntries();
            }
          }, errorHandler);
        };

        readEntries(); // Start reading dirs.
      }
    }
```

Reference : [Chrome File System Example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/filesystem-access)

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage#read It looks like you first call `entry.file(callback)` to get a file. Then you need to use a FileReader to read the file, then you can upload it using FormData or whatever you like.

Comment: Hello, I tried that but it gives me same problem as this guy has [Using forEach loop while converting from FileEntry object to File object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397767/using-foreach-loop-while-converting-from-fileentry-object-to-file-object) , It's not entering in that part of code.

Answer (score 1):

As @gengkev said in his comment, use `entry.file(function(f) { ... })` to extract a File object that can be used for a form submission.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating your answer? Cause it will certainly answer my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65131231/send-file-to-php-server-with-js -> If you can post an answer in my question link, I can accept it.